# Validation Message for radio button in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, radio-button, radiobuttonfor

Currently I am creating online form, so I have a issue with validating radio button field. I managed to create validation message for all my textbox, but it seems like creating validation message for radiobutton is way different than creating validation for textbox?

**My Problem is**
I have radio button for gender, "Male" and "Female", how should I validate these field?

**My ViewModel**

```
    public class PersonalValidator
{
    public int personalInfoId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Gender is required")]
    public string gender { get; set; }

    public string occupation { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> maritalId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> registrationId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> eduInfoId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> monthlyId { get; set; }
}
```

**My Razor**

```
        <tr>
        <td> Gender</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.personalValid.gender, "Male") Male
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.personalValid.gender)

            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.personalValid.gender, "Female") Female
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.personalValid.gender)
        </td>
<tr>
```

**My Controller**

```
         [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestValidation(RegisterInfoPA viewmodel)
    {
        using (var database = new TMXEntities())
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var personalVM = viewmodel.personalValid;                

                     //save personal info
                    personalInfo personalDB = new personalInfo();

                    personalDB.gender = personalVM.gender;                                       
                    personalDB.occupation = personalVM.occupation;
                    personalDB.maritalId = personalVM.maritalId;
                    personalDB.eduInfoId = personalVM.eduInfoId;
                    personalDB.monthlyId = personalVM.eduInfoId;

                    db.personalInfoes.Add(personalDB);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                   return RedirectToAction("SuccessfullyCreated");

            }

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you need to validate? Are both radio buttons off initially and you want to check that one has been selected?

Comment: yes, both radio button are not selected, so when user want to submit the form, the validation message will appear to ask user to select one. User cant leave it unselected.

Comment: What are the errors that u r getting?

Comment: for validation, there is no error, it just not displaying the error message like it do with my textbox. so since the validation message is not working(means it didnt stop from posting, continue with my code..) so it makes my required field as null <br>

Comment: my required field>>   personalDB.gender = personalVM.gender; i got nullexception error.

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine (although you only need one  `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.personalValid.gender)`). And there is no difference between creating a validation message for a textbox or a radio button group. Show your `RegisterInfoPA` model, in particular is the `personalValid` a field or a property.

Comment: but I am getting error once I submitted the form, I am getting  System.NullReferenceException at this line >>  personalDB.gender = personalVM.gender;

Comment: since the user did not select anything, so it should display the error message right?.. :confuse:

Comment: **Again**,  show your `RegisterInfoPA` model - If you getting a `NullRefernceException` it means `personalVM` is `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it is a bit late but it might help someone else. Since you are using viewmodel, I think the easy and best solution is by using **AddModelError**.

**In Your Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestValidation(RegisterInfoPA viewmodel)
{
    using (var database = new TMXEntities())
    {
       //VALIDATE FIRST
       MainValidation(viewmodel)

       //Proceed to process data
       -----------codes------------------           
    }
}

   public void MainValidation(RegisterInfoPA validationData)
    {
            if (validationData.personalValid.gender == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("gender", "Please select gender");
            }

    }
```

Hope this helps.